# Remove multiple fragment transactions in Android - IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I reveive an error when trying to pop the backstack after adding several fragments.
In my app I have one main activity, and multiple fragments.

The error occurs in the following way: First the user is in frag 1. He navigates to frag 2, and then to frag 3. This navigation is done by using `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`

After going from frag 1 -> frag 2 -> frag 3, I navigate to frag 4 the same way. However, when I am finished in frag 4, I replace fragment 4 with fragment 3 without adding to the backstack. This way I can include a bundle in the fragment's arguments (instead of just popping the backstack). When I am back in frag 3, and if I hit the back button, the back stack will be popped, but I receive this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: EditFragment...
```

Note: I do not want to the pop the backstack when going from fragment 4 to fragment 3 because  sometimes I end up having a more complicated navigation than the one explained here.

Comment: probably there is a simpler implementation you can follow, for example passing data between fragments... I don't think yours is a good way to use fragments.

Comment: @albemala: Ok, I realize it can probably be made simpler, and likely I will make som changes. But I am still curious why the error occurs